# Triggering a fragment's transition animation without popBackStack()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, fragmenttransaction

I've chosen to hide/show my fragments during navigation for smoother animations.

To display a fragment, I add an animation :

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.from_right,
                    R.anim.to_left, R.anim.from_left, R.anim.to_right);
```

Then I simply hide previous one, show next one.

The problem is if I want to "popback" the fragment, I don't use the normal `addToBackStack(null);` 
Instead I just hide the previous one and show the next one again. But this way the animation is not played. I don't want to save which fragment should use which animation every time.

How do I use the animations I initially set up in setCustomAnimations when I leave the fragment, in the same way a `popBackStack` would do it?